# Navbar keeps going above background image with a white box around it instead of being transparent over the image

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and can't seem to figure out what's going wrong with my navbar. I have the following code for my navbar:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-default" id="headNavbar">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" style="font-family: 'Roboto Flex', sans-serif;" href="#topWithBackground"><b><span class="text-android-green">Title</span></b></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          Menu
        </button>
        <!-- Rest of Navbar Content  -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" class="link blue-hover" href="#about"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i> About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#projects"><i class="fa-solid fa-code"></i> Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#education"><i class="fa-solid fa-graduation-cap"></i> Education</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <!-- Maybe change this to call icon -->
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact"><i class="fa-solid fa-address-card"></i> Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/resume" target="blank"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-pdf"></i> Resume</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

This results in something that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSxKF.png). The crossed out portion is the title, and the links are white so they're blending in with the white background. Instead of it looking like this, I'd like for the navbar to overlay on top of the background, but I don't want it to be fixed to the top. I've tried doing

```
  .navbar-default {background-color:transparent}
```

in my CSS file, but this seems to make no difference.
How can I fix this? Thanks!

Edit: Here is my background image code

```
 header.masthead {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.9), rgba(0,0,0,0.1)), url("/img/orlando_lake_eola_night.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    *background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: left center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code w/ `background-image` also?

Comment: Added the background image code @Kameron

Comment: Invalid HTML - Forgot to close `</header>` and don't need a closing `img` tag.

Comment: My mistake, that was the wrong code. I added the actual CSS for my background image

Comment: You say you are using Bootstrap-5 but tagged it with Bootstrap-4 and your markup looks like Bootstrap-4 which is it?

Comment: It's Bootstrap 5, my mistake for the tag